# fontspec ruins Lilypond's note spacing

Tags: spacing, xetex, fontspec, lilypond

I use `lilypond-book` to include music examples in my TeX document, but it seems that `fontspec` breaks the horizontal spacing between the notes:

without `fontspec`
[image: without fontspec]

with fontspec
[image: with fontspec]

This MWE shows the error

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

%\usepackage{fontspec}

\begin{document}
This is a \lilypond[notime,fragment,staffsize=15]{bes' a' c' b'} test
\end{document}
```

when compiled with

```
lilypond-book test.lytex
xelatex text.tex
```

I guess that `fontspec` changes a certain font setting, which `lilypond` expect to have an other value. Maybe this can be fixed by adding something to `\preLilyPondExample` …

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try compiling with:

```
lilypond-book --latex-program=xelatex test.lytex
xelatex test.tex
```

Using xelatex all the way through the compilation should solve your problems.

Using your MWE, this produces:

[image: Nicely formatted lilypond example with XeLaTeX]

Which is what you'd expect. We can also use some nice OpenType features (isn't fontspec great?):

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\newcommand*{\defaultfontfamily}{Calluna}
\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text, Ligatures={Discretionary, Common, Rare}}
\setmainfont{\defaultfontfamily}

\begin{document}
This is a \lilypond[notime,fragment,staffsize=15]{bes' a' c' b'} test
\end{document}
```

and everything still works:

[image: LilyPond book with XeLaTeX and Calluna]

Comment: Great, thanks! I tried `latex-programm` but missed the `--` before the option O:-) BTW: Is it possible to set the options `notime,fragment,staffsize=15` global?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of; I always just use `\begin{lilypond}[options]`; maybe you could define a \lilypondoptions macro and just pass that in everytime you need options (so you at least have the ability to update options in a single place).

Comment: Unfortunately this won’t work since the `.lytex` file is preprocessed with `lilypond-book` which isn’t aware of LaTeXs macro expansion.

Comment: Oh, right, oops. You still might be able to do it; you'd just have to run it through xelatex first (with some sort of dummy environment specified for the lilypond environment) and have it do some pre-expansion and spit out a temp file for lilypond-book to process... probably not worth it at that point.

Comment: Hm … two precompilings are too much in that case, then I’ll type the option verbatim and use search’n’replace if I want to change them …